# Android Swipe Velocity

Tags: android, gesture, swipe

What is the best way to compute the speed/velocity of a swipe? Is there some fancy class or function that provides this or do I need to perform this by measuring touch up and touch down? I did some searching but came up empty - perhaps I dont have the right terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`OnGestureListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) has the following method, providing the velocity for the x- and y-axis:

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
```

You can implement the `OnGestureListener`, or, from the docs:

> If you want to listen for all the different gestures then implement
>   this interface. If you only want to listen for a subset it might be
>   easier to extend GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.